# How can I determine the address from a private key?

Tags: address, api, address-generation, bitcoinj

From [the steps in the wiki](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Wallet_import_format), take this example private key:

```
0C28FCA386C7A227600B2FE50B7CAE11EC86D3BF1FBE471BE89827E19D72AA1D
```

When I import this into Electrum, I find these values:

Address:

```
1GAehh7TsJAHuUAeKZcXf5CnwuGuGgyX2S
```

Public Key:

```
04d0de0aaeaefad02b8bdc8a01a1b8b11c696bd3d66a2c5f10780d95b7df42645cd85228a6fb29940e858e7e55842ae2bd115d1ed7cc0e82d934e929c97648cb0a
```

How can I determine the address from the key (without using Electrum)?

I understand that the derivation route is private key -> public key -> address, so I've found a way to generate the public key in Java using [BitcoinJ](https://bitcoinj.org/):

```
BigInteger privkey = new BigInteger("0C28FCA386C7A227600B2FE50B7CAE11EC86D3BF1FBE471BE89827E19D72AA1D", 16);
byte[] bytes = org.bitcoinj.core.ECKey.publicKeyFromPrivate(privkey, false);
String publickey = new BigInteger(1, bytes).toString(16);
while(publickey.length() < 130){
    publickey = "0" + publickey;
}
Log.d("public",publickey);
```

It gives the correct public key as shown above, so I just need to find a way to get the address.

I don't know much about different address formats, but my goal is to use the address to check the balance using some public API like [blockchain.com](https://www.blockchain.com/btc/address/1GAehh7TsJAHuUAeKZcXf5CnwuGuGgyX2S). I guess this is the P2PKH-type address.

I tried this:

```
NetworkParameters params = MainNetParams.get();
ECKey key = ECKey.fromPrivate(privkey);
String address = LegacyAddress.fromKey(params, key).toString();
Log.d("address",address);
```

Which gives me this address:

```
1LoVGDgRs9hTfTNJNuXKSpywcbdvwRXpmK
```

But the address is different.

Comment: Do you mean 1... address, that is compressed or uncompressed, or a SegWit native (Bech32) address or SegWit nested legacy compatible 3... adress. Or even an m-of-n multisig address? If you just want an address, this should help: https://gobittest.appspot.com/Address The link to the answer is in your question, how can we help? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @MCCCS I added more details, but I want to do it programatically in Java

Comment: Does this help: https://github.com/bitcoinj/bitcoinj/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/org/bitcoinj/examples/PrivateKeys.java#L58-L62 ?

Comment: @MCCCS I tried it but it gives a different address with a different balance, so I assume it's an unrelated address. I added my code above

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both "1LoVG.." and the other one are valid legacy (1...) addresses made using the same private key. They are different since one of them uses the **compressed public key** (you might want to look this up) while 1GAehh7 uses the uncompressed public key. Always use the same compress-format for an address, and it's advisable to create new addresses in compressed format since it saves bytes and transaction fees.

To make the uncompressed-public-keyed address (compressed is the default in BitcoinJ):

```
ECKey key = ECKey.fromPrivate(privkey);
key = key.decompress();
String address = LegacyAddress.fromKey(params, key).toString();
```